# Is it possible to write syntax like - ()()?

Tags: c#

I read in an ebook somewhere (which I'm desperate to find again), that, by using delegates, it is possible to write code which has syntax as follows:

```
 ()(); // where delegate precedes this.
```

Can anyone provide any details how this would be possible/in what situation this would occur?

Comment: What possible purpose could there be for this (other than having two empty eyes stare at you in code)?

Comment: This question really brings out the obscure side of the Force - I am impressed at seeing such bright minds competing enthusiastically to produce genuinely, deeply horrifying code!

Comment: @Mathias: Evil code is the funnest. And the "best" part is, the more evil your code becomes, the more evil you want it to be.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can do slightly better than the examples given so far, in fact... you can extend it arbitrarily:

```
class Test
{
    delegate Hofstadter Hofstadter();

    static void Main()
    {
        // Unfortunately I'm clearly not as smart as the real thing
        Hofstadter douglas = () => null;

        douglas()()()()()()();
    }
}
```

And here's another horrible alternative, for extra ASCII art:

```
class Test
{
    delegate __ ___();
    delegate ___ __(___ _);

    static void Main()
    {
        ___ _ = () => null;

        _ ()((_))();
    }
}
```

Please never ever, ever do this.

EDIT: One last one - although it's as much about just replacing things with underscores as anything else, and reusing names wherever possible:

```
class Test
{
    delegate void _();
    delegate __<_> ___<_>();
    delegate ___<_> __<_>(___<_> ____);

    static ___<_> ____<_>(___<_> ____) { return ____; }
    static __<_> ____<_>() { return ____<_>; }

    static void Main()
    {
        ((__<_>)____)(____<_>)();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this summons a velociraptor.

Comment: A trick similar to the first one (a delegate that accepts a itself as a parameter) can be "useful": the Y combinator! (http://blogs.msdn.com/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx WARNING: not for the feeble of mind!)

Comment: It's actually a secret incantation that grants superhero C# abilities to the person that says it. Unfortunately, it works only once and Jon's already use it.

Comment: @Coronatus: Yes, I think it's time to make it CW just so it doesn't look like a rep grab attempt.

Comment: this is _required_ way to use delegates when using classes in the System.Net.MorseCode namespace.

Comment: In the 1st case you get a null reference exception. This can be fixed by `douglas` returning itself, but needing to separate definiing `douglas` from its assignment.

Comment: @Richard: Use the Y combinator! `Hofstadter douglas = Y(Y)(_ => _);`

Comment: @Jon Skeet - well deserved rep.  It's gems like this that make this site so fantastic.

Comment: Wow.  This is inspiring!  I think I'm going to only use underscores from now on......just kidding! :)

Comment: Has Damian Conway switched from Perl to C#?

Comment: ()((_))() - Holy crap is that GOAT-C#

Comment: Strong are you with the dark side.

Comment: Nothing beats Haskell's owl: `((.)$(.))` (which compiles and has a type `(a -> b -> c) -> a -> (a1 -> b) -> a1 -> c`). http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree

Comment: Um, have any of you seen my brain? i think it's dripping off of those underscores....

Comment: I'm not up on my ASCII art, what are those supposed to be?

Comment: @tomas Sorry if I don't see an owl. :-(

Answer (score 35):

Here's a sample program that demonstrates this:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static Action GetMethod()
    {
        return () => Console.WriteLine("Executing");
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        GetMethod()();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

That being said, I wouldn't ever do this in production code.  It's very unexpected.

---

Edit: Just in case you want to see something even uglier... [especially the "`()()[()=>{}]()`"]:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        (new Program()).Confusion();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public Action this[Action index]
    {
        get {
            return () => Console.WriteLine("Executing");
        }
    }

    Func<Program> GetInstance()
    {
        return () => this;
    }

    void Confusion()
    {
        // This is particularly ugly...
        GetInstance()()[()=>{}]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude. That is just...I don't know. I am going to be looking for places to do this in a production app now, though it be an act of great evil.

Answer (score 12):

You just need a little self referencing, and you can call it as many times as you like:

```
delegate Foo Foo();

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo f = null;
        f = () => f;
        // Add more "()" as you feel like...
        f()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here `f` is an "identity" function of a different sort, returning itself (rather than its parameter).

Answer (score 9):

```
static void Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}

static Action Bar()
{
    return new Action(Foo);
}

static void Main()
{
    Func<Action> func = new Func<Action>(Bar);
    func()();

    Bar()();
}
```

prints

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

This works, because `func()` and `Bar()` return an `Action` delegate which can be invoked using normal method invocation syntax.

Comment: I think this is the most common case; code that needs to lookup a different delegate depending upon the circumstances. I've got some code that does `ConstructFunc(key)(obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
delegate void FunctionA();
delegate FunctionA FunctionB();

void TestA() { }
FunctionA TestB() { return TestA; }

void Main()
{
   TestB()();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function that returns a delegate that you would commonly then attach to a signal, but you want to just call that function right away, you might use this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out this blog post by Bertrand Leroy for something similar: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/03/30/a-c-implementation-of-the-callstream-pattern.aspx

But that actually does something semi-useful :)